# WATIR: Is there a reason why browser scrolling won't work?

Tags: ruby, scroll, watir

I'm trying to use **browser.scroll.to :bottom** but nothing happens.
I know that it works because I've tried it on public facing sites such as the BBC and Wikipedia, but for some reason, these scroll commands don't work on our in-house browser based app.

Does anyone know of any reasons or settings that could be preventing this from happening?
Things such as **browser.refresh** and **browser.window.maximize** work fine but the scrolling literally refuses to budge.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
require 'watir'
require_relative 'regression_config_bob01.rb'
require 'date'
require 'faker'
require 'slack-notifier'
require 'watir-scroll'

user_name = "blah"
password = "blah"

test_env = "the Site"


browser = Watir::Browser.new 

browser.goto(test_env)

# Login
browser.text_field(:name => 'P101_USERNAME').set user_name
browser.text_field(:tabindex=> '2').set password
browser.link(:text => "Log in").click

sleep 20

browser.wd.action.scroll_by(0, 1000).perform # Suggested Scroll line

print "done"

sleep 30
```

temporary_exp.rb:62:in `<main>': undefined method` scroll_by' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::W3CActionBuilder:0x000000014ac54bd0 @bridge=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge:0x000000014ac1e440 @capabilities=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Capabilities:0x000000014ac1e940 @capabilities={:proxy=>nil, :browser_name=>"chrome", :browser_version=>"106.0.5249.119", :platform_name=>"mac os x", :accept_insecure_certs=>false, :page_load_strategy=>"normal", :implicit_timeout=>0, :page_load_timeout=>300000, :script_timeout=>30000, :remote_session_id=>nil, :accessibility_checks=>nil, :profile=>nil, :rotatable=>nil, :device=>nil, "chrome"=>{"chromedriverVersion"=>"105.0.5195.52 (412c95e518836d8a7d97250d62b29c2ae6a26a85-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#853})", "userDataDir"=>"/var/folders/hb/h_0h2t79183fkkppsr6r19nc0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.BV85VD"}, "goog:chromeOptions"=>{"debuggerAddress"=>"localhost:50818"}, "networkConnectionEnabled"=>false, "setWindowRect"=>true, "strictFileInteractability"=>false, "unhandledPromptBehavior"=>"dismiss and notify", "webauthn:extension:credBlob"=>true, "webauthn:extension:largeBlob"=>true, "webauthn:virtualAuthenticators"=>true}>, @session_id="8c59128dd44054681f62819d2fed25cf", @http=#<Watir::HttpClient:0x000000014ab6e298 @open_timeout=60, @read_timeout=nil, @server_url=#<URI::HTTP [http://127.0.0.1:9515/>](http://127.0.0.1:9515/%3E), @proxy=nil, @http=#<Net::HTTP 127.0.0.1:9515 open=true>>, @file_detector=nil, @escaper=#URI::RFC2396_Parser:0x000000014b0cbbc8, @manage=#<Selenium::WebDriver::W3CManager:0x000000014ab640b8 @bridge=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge:0x000000014ac1e440 ...>, @window=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Window:0x000000014aa17ca0 @bridge=#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge:0x000000014ac1e440 ...>>>>, @devices=[#<Selenium::WebDriver::Interactions::PointerInput:0x000000014ac54f40 @name="mouse", @actions=[], @kind=:mouse>, #<Selenium::WebDriver::Interactions::KeyInput:0x000000014ac54d38 @name="keyboard", @actions=[]>], @async=false> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Is the content on the page being loaded asynchronously? You could have a situation where the initial part of the page loads and the Watir scroll commands scrolls to the bottom successfully. Then the remaining asynchronous content finishes loading, pushing the bottom of the page further down (without changing what is in the viewport). This makes it look like Watir didn't scroll correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The current scroll implementation is using javascript to move the page around. For some reason your app is not responding to the JS commands in the normal way.

Selenium has recently released native scrolling via the drivers that Watir has not yet been updated. Take a look at the Selenium documentation on it: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/?language=ruby

To use this in watir, you just need to add the line to the top: `driver = browser.wd`

So to scroll down by 2000 pixels, you can do:

```
driver = browser.wd
driver.action
      .scroll_by(0, 2000)
      .perform
```

Comment: Thanks Titus. I'm still a relative newbie. In my code above, where would I place your suggested line. Also, do I need to 'require' anything further or adjust anything?

Comment: Watir is just a wrapper for Selenium at this point, so it is already required. Just add that line of code after you define `browser` and before you want to use `driver` and it should "just work." :)

Comment: Thanks Titus. It didn't work. Could you just check my code above and check if it seems in order. I've added the line you suggested but should browser.scroll.to :bottom be modified in anyway to include the 'wd'?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you could ignore Watir::Scroll and use the methods in Selenium documentation by getting the driver object from the browser. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

like Titus said, Watir is a wrapper for Selenium and lets you write shorter and prettier code, like

```rb
browser.scroll.to :bottom
browser.scroll.to :top
browser.element(id: "asd").scroll.to
```

but when (for any reason) it doesn't work you can use [Selenium syntax](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/?language=ruby) directly by sending commands to `browser.wd` instead `browser` like this:

```rb
browser.wd.action.scroll_by(0, 1000).perform #this scrolls bottom
browser.wd.action.scroll_by(0, -1000).perform #this scrolls top  
browser.wd.action.scroll_to(browser.wd.find_element(id: "asd")).perform
```

but instead of writing `browser.wd` every time you need to talk to driver directly, you can type `driver = browser.wd` so your code is more clear:

```rb
driver = browser.wd
driver.action.scroll_by(0, 1000).perform #this scrolls bottom
driver.action.scroll_by(0, -1000).perform #this scrolls top  
some_element = driver.find_element(id: "asd")
driver.action.scroll_to(some_element).perform
```

There are countless examples where using Watir is more efficient than talking to driver directly, you just happened to encounter an edge case.

Also try avoiding `sleep` when possible, instead, [wait for something](http://watir.com/guides/waiting/) to show, like:

```rb
browser.element(id: 'asd').wait_until(&:present?)
browser.element(id: 'asd').wait_until({ |el| el.text == "Success" })
some_element = browser.element(id: 'asd')
browser.wait_until(30){some_element.present?}
```

Instead of `.element` you can use [correct subclass](http://watir.com/guides/elements/) like `.div`, `.button`, `.span` etc

Comment: Thanks @Luka. I tried implementing one of your suggested lines (see code above) but an error was returned as a result. Can you see if there is anything obvious wrong or that I'm missing?

Comment: @bobbie_j check if you have selenium-webdriver 4.2+ with command
```gem list selenium```